# KeyError: '[17] not found in axis'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to drop raws into my dataframe with my index but I have a problem in the raw 17.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(tweets_df1)):
    if tweets_df1.iloc[i]['Text'].find('https') != -1:
        print(i)
        tweets_df1.drop(index=i,axis=0)
```

But I have this error in the last line with the df.drop and I don't know why. If you know you the solution it will be helpful.

Here is the text dataframe:

*Delivery with drones on thousands of everyday items in one hour or less.Taking flight later this year in Lockeford, California. 'link 1' 'link 2'*

Comment: can you show the df as well? It seems like there is no index 17

Comment: What does your dataframe look like?  Does it actually have an index label `17`?

Comment: Hi, yes there is an index in the line 17 with text and links to it

Comment: What if you run `tweets_df1=tweets_df1.reset_index()` before the loop? Do you still get the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think this is going to do what you expect. [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) by default is not an in place operation. So the loop does not remove those indices. But if you do drop them, you’ll run into trouble using iloc, because you’re changing the shape of your dataframe during the loop. I think what you’re looking for is this:

```py
for i in tweets_df1.index:
    if tweets_df1.loc[i, 'Text'].find('https') != -1:
        print(i)
        tweets_df1.drop(index=i,axis=0, inplace=True)
```

That said, resizing within a for loop like this is very inefficient. Would be better to do this in a vectorized way using pandas [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods):

```py
tweets_filtered = tweets_df1[
    tweets_df1.Text.str.contains('https')
]
```